# Valid api request returns null

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, curl

I am working on an API from RIOT games. I use this code to in order to let it work:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ini_set("display_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Electronic Arts, Legendary, Kiddo?api_key=');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($response, true);
     //var_dump($json);
     //$json = array_pop($json);

                echo $json['id'] . ',' . $json['name'] . ',' . $json['summonerLevel'] . "<br/>";
?>
```

When I directly paste the api call url in my browser this will return:

```
{
    "kiddo": {
        "id": 35037868,
        "name": "kiddo",
        "profileIconId": 505,
        "summonerLevel": 30,
        "revisionDate": 1412534473000
    },
    "legendary": {
        "id": 229888,
        "name": "Legendary",
        "profileIconId": 592,
        "summonerLevel": 30,
        "revisionDate": 1412259698000
    },
    "electronicarts": {
        "id": 31827832,
        "name": "Electronic Arts",
        "profileIconId": 575,
        "summonerLevel": 30,
        "revisionDate": 1412541482000
    }
}
```

But when I execute the first code block, the `var_dump($json)` only returns `NULL`
I think there must be a simple mistake which I am blind for, could anyone help me out?

Comment: Forgot the api key in the url?

Comment: I left it out on purpose - its there in the real code. The arrays shown below are real results from api call.

Comment: Have you used [`curl_error($ch)`](http://php.net/curl_error)?

Comment: perhaps it's timing out? Could for instance bump up the connection timeout if your default_socket_timeout is too low  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen, I didnt before, just executed it. What should I see? It returns nothing, probably an emptry string?

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness, Tried, no result.

Comment: ...and you have the curl extension installed and working other than this script? Just checking ;)

Comment: Yes, I have done other api requests with somewhat the exact same code that went very well. Everything is up2date on server side. Well like, you see the array that pops out, how would you program it to see the results of 'id','name','summonerLevel'. Would you say my code is bad or is there something missing? Im getting the feeling that im doing something wrong.

Comment: @floppy Hey, think I got it. Try replacing the spaces in the url with %20 so it's properly encoded.

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness does not work :/ It tells me that the given parameters are undefined id,name,summonerLevel. When I remove the %20, the code works again but still returns NULL.

Comment: @floppy Well I tried your code with my suggestion and got it to work earlier, even though I got an access denied reply obviously since I didn't have the key.

Comment: Dear NewInTheBusiness i have got it to work also. See christians code, somehow or something was missing. Probably an inappropriate approach of the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is to do with spaces in your url. you need to put %20

`/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Electronic%20Arts,%20Legendary,%20Kiddo?api_key=`

complete example

```
$url = str_replace(' ', '%20', 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Electronic Arts, Legendary, Kiddo?api_key=');

$ch = curl_init($url);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // do not set to false, vunerable to man in the middle attacks
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

$errno = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg = curl_error($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($errno, $errmsg, $httpcode, $resp);
```

Comment: When I put this in my actual code this returns: 

Notice: Undefined index: id in /hermes/bosoraweb130/b411/ipg.notsureifpossiblecom/index.php on line 31 
Notice: Undefined index: name in /hermes/bosoraweb130/b411/ipg.notsureifpossiblecom/index.php on line 31 
Notice: Undefined index: summonerLevel in /hermes/bosoraweb130/b411/ipg.notsureifpossiblecom/index.php on line 31

Comment: is that because you are getting back a string and not converting it to a json and therefore the reference id, name and index are not defined. do a print_r on the response from curl

Comment: `int(0) string(0)
""
int(200) string(347)
"{"
kiddo ":{"
id ":35037868,"
name ":"
kiddo ","
profileIconId ":505,"
summonerLevel ":30,"
revisionDate ":1412534473000},"
legendary ":{"
id ":229888,"
name ":"
Legendary ","
profileIconId ":592,"
summonerLevel ":30,"
revisionDate ":1412259698000},"
electronicarts ":{"
id ":31827832,"
name ":"
Electronic Arts ","
profileIconId ":575,"
summonerLevel ":30,"
revisionDate ":1412549273000}}"`


thats the return from your 1:1 copied code.

Comment: the keys all have spaces :/ for example " id ". that sucks. you will have to json_decode and then loop over the array doing a trim on the keys and values or do a preg_replace before json_decode

Comment: That should not be normal, as you can see in the first post about the arrays that originally comes from live data sets.

Comment: yep, the developers of that site need to be told... compare it to this one https://dev-api.fxc.im/v2/data/countries, no spaces

Comment: But how could this be different from the one that I directly get from putting the api url in adress bar (first post arrays) and calling through json(result from 1 post above)? Thats even possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62495/discussion-between-christian-and-floppy).

Answer (score 0):

Paste url in Browser, check if that works. Browser encodes url and then fetches result,

Use the same encoded url in your code, that would work.

Comment: firefox wont change the url displayed

Comment: same for chrome, the url I posted in my code retursn with the arrays. The url is not the problem. its something in my code that does not properly returns the code.